# structure: I stood guard

Tags: complements

> “I need you with me,” she said. “Don’t go away again.”
>
> But I hadn’t gone away! I had been abducted!
>
> I could feel the sleep pressing down on her.
>
> “I need you with me,” she said. “I’m so afraid. I’m so afraid.”
>
> It’s okay, I said. I’m here.
>
> She rolled to the edge of the bed and looked down at me, her eyes
> glazed.
>
> “Get me through tonight,” she said. “That’s all I need. Protect me.
> Don’t let it happen tonight. Enzo, please. You’re the only one who can
> help.”
>
> I will, I said.
>
> “You’re the only one. Don’t worry about that nurse; I sent her home.”
>
> I looked over to the corner, and the crinkly old woman was gone.
>
> “I don’t need her,” she said. “Only you can protect me. Please. Don’t
> let it happen tonight.”
>
> I didn’t sleep at all that night. I stood ***guard***, waiting for the demon
> to show his face. The demon was coming for Eve, but he would have to
> get past me first, and I was ready. I noted every sound, every creak,
> every change in air density, and by standing or shifting my weight, I
> silently made it clear to the demon that he would have to contend with
> me if he intended to take Eve.
>
> (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)

I guess that *guard* is predicative for *I* and has no article because Enzo is the only guard. If he were one of many guards, the matrix would have been *I stood a guard*. (As in: Bill was *head boy* and Charlie was *captain of Quidditch*. Now Percy’s *a prefect* - Harry Potter book one, p99) Is this right, or is there other structure for the example?

Comment: No - there are no corresponding expressions like *stand captain* or *stand prefect*. The verb [to stand guard {over}](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stand+guard+over) is pretty much a "one-off". Although for semantic purposes you might best understand it as a paraphrasing of *I stood as/adopted the role of **a** guard*, that article  never occurs in the actual idiomatic standard. It's not meaningfully subject to grammatical analysis at this level, any more than the related *to stand watch [over]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's actually a cluster here; I've heard the expression *stand sentry* as well. I'm pretty sure there's an archaic construction these are just relicts of (possibly related to the dictionary.com #23), but I'm not familiar enough with ME/EME to identify it.

Comment: @chrylis: Agreed "one-off" was a bit of an overstatement. All I really meant was it's not a "productive" construction that could be used with a wide variety of words. Also, it seems to me *stand guard, stand watch* derive from the *verb* usages. But since there's no verb *to sentry*, that one's probably based on the fact that the nouns *sentry, guard* can be synonyms. It's not likely to work for many/any other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "stand", in this case, means *to perform the duty* and is a transitive verb, which has at least one object. You can find some examples in the dictionaries:

> **stand** (*v*.) to perform the duty of or participate in as part of one's job or duty: *to stand watch aboard ship*. (from [Dictionary.com, meaning #27](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stand?s=t); you might have to expand to see this)
>
> **stand** (*v*.) to perform the duty of <*stand* guard> (from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand), transitive verb meaning #4a)

The word "guard" you indicate describes the kind/type of duty, not a person working on the duty. Therefore, "guard" in the sentence is uncountable and requires no article.